# Google console - You need to add a physical address in account details

Tags: android, google-play-console

When releasing an Android app, Google gives a warning: "You need to add a physical address in account details."

But I have already an address under "account details".

Comment: Seems like in addition there is a "physical address" under "Developer Page"

Comment: I think you should submit your answer to your question and mark it as best answer, because this is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like in addition there is a "physical address" under "Developer Page"

Comment: Not accurate as of 2024

Comment: Except that, for me, there is no "Developer Page" item at all. It doesn't exist. I'm assuming this is because I've not yet promoted my app past the Closed Testing requirement in preparation for App Store release, and that the Developer Page item will appear later... that's just a guess, though.